# Issue while installing pip on RHEL6 server with no internet

Tags: python-2.7, pip, rhel6

We have python 2.7 installed on server
Tried installing pip  by following steps
1) downloaded pip-19.1.1 tar file from  internet on local machine(ubuntu)
2) transfered file to server and extracted the content
2) ran setup.py file present in the folder using comman python setup.py
but giving below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/Python-2.7.12/Lib/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/Python-2.7.12/Lib/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/bin/Python-2.7.12/Lib/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/bin/Python-2.7.12/Lib/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/bin/Python-2.7.12/Lib/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/bin/Python-2.7.12/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 520, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/bin/Python-2.7.12/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 472, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/bin/Python-2.7.12/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 356, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata\
```

Also downloaded get-pip.py file from link https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py. Executed python get-pip.py on server but giving the above same error.